# How to figure out if mysql index fits entirely in memory

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

Is there a way to determine whether a mysql index fits entirely in available memory? If so, how would I:

- Determine size of mysql indexes
- Determine available memory for the application
- Determine if the indexes fit entirely in memory

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Depends on Storage Engine

## MyISAM (Caches Index Pages From .MYI files)

```
SELECT FLOOR(SUM(index_length)/POWER(1024,2)) IndexSizesMB
FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='MyISAM' AND
table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','performance_schema','mysql');
```

Subtract that from `key_buffer_size`. If the answer > 0, then Yes

## InnoDB (Caches Data and Index Pages)

```
SELECT FLOOR(SUM(data_length+index_length)/POWER(1024,2)) InnoDBSizeMB
FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='InnoDB';
```

Subtract that from `innodb_buffer_pool_size`. If the answer > 0, then Yes

I wrote about this in the [**DBA StackExchange**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/2194/877)

On a dedicated DB Server, make sure `InnoDBSizeMB+IndexSizesMB` does not exceed 75% of RAM.

Comment: Thanks, does the following seem realistic? `innodb_buffer_pool_size=134217728` - `above-query=283164672` = `-148946944`. If this is the case, should I increase my `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, or what would be the next step here?

Comment: Your buffer pool is 128M. Your InnoDBSize is 270M. So, raise `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 300M.

Comment: I redid the query to do MB instead of Bytes.

Comment: Is that correct? For InnoDB it returns the size of the whole table (data+index) why?

Comment: @TomášFejfar Yes it is correct because InnoDB caches data pages and index pages. Therefore, you have to express `data_length+index_length`.

Comment: Ouch, that's a lot of data :(

Comment: The query for InnoDB appears to count data _and_ indexes, but if you only want to know if indexes fit, can you just check `SUM(index_length)`?  Obviously there are data pages cached, so it will depend on how hot your data is to increase that size to cache enough indexes and data pages, so the number needs to be bigger by some percentage depending on workload...but does it seem reasonable just to `SUM(index_length)` and add to that some application-specific additional room for data?

Comment: @KJ7LNW The Buffer Pool is designed to accommodate data and index pages. You cannot segregate them and measure them independently since they share one buffer. Even if you plan to use covering indexes extensively, the available Buffer Pool is still fair game for data pages and index pages alike.

Answer (score 3):

To find memory available to MySQL, look in `my.cnf`, likely located at: `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

```
key_buffer_size = 264M
```

To find size of indexes for a table: `SHOW TABLE status FROM [DBNAME]`

Comment: In my my.cnf file I do not have any options related to memory defined. What is the specific option here that would need to be defined?