# How can I index - optimize this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT id, terrain, occupied, c_type 
FROM map 
WHERE x >= $x-$radius 
  AND x <= $x+$radius 
  AND y >= $y-$radius 
  AND y <= $y+$radius 
   ORDER BY 
     x ASC, 
     y ASC
```

My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `map` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `occupied` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `c_type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `x` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `y` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `terrain` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

I removed all indexes except PRIMARY KEY, because I am unsure how does indexing works with SQL.
What can I do to tune this query? Thanks...

This is not a duplicate,check comments!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567981/how-do-mysql-indexes-work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do MySQL indexes work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567981/how-do-mysql-indexes-work)

Comment: When you're using WHERE statement database search data by fields you're specified. So you can add indexes in 'x' and 'y'.

Comment: . @AlexSlipknot Could you show how would the index look like if I want to avoid table scan altogether? Like, in what order should I place x,y,id, occupied column etc so optimizer would use it efficiently?

Comment: @SolarBear That question is a little bit helpfull, however I still don't understand how to implement index for my query. Should I place x and y first,and when the rest of columns in a same order as I define SELECT ... or should x and y be at the end,i.e. First select columns and x,y. And what about if I want to select x and y too? How then should index be structured? I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Metal Castles just create indexes in your table. Leave query as is.

Comment: @AlexSlipknot Yes, but in which column order? `x, y, id, terrain, occupied, c_type` or `id, terrain, occupied, c_type, x, y`?

Comment: Order does not matter

Comment: @AlexSlipknot and OP: just to be clear, index order CAN matter. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252279/mysql-indices-and-order.

Comment: Also, indexes with more columns will end up larger and may not be able to fully fit into memory : see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748629/how-to-figure-out-if-mysql-index-fits-entirely-in-memory for more info.

Comment: @SolarBear - indexes are cached block-by-block.  So, whether it "fully fits in memory" is not quite a valid point.

Comment: @AlexSlipknot - Separate indexes on `x` and `y`:  MySQL will use only one index.

Comment: @MetalCastles - `INDEX(x,y,id)` -- the `id` adds nothing useful.  Having all the columns (hence "covering") is potentially good.  However, as SolarBear points out, "bulk may slow things down".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I added index `gmp` with columns `x, y, id, terrain, occupied, c_type` and EXPLAIN SELECT displays:

```
id: 1

select_type: SIMPLE

table: map

type: range

possible_keys: gmp

key: gmp

key_len: 8

ref: NULL

rows: 1955

Extra: Using where; Using index
```

So, I guess it works now.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do with *that* query is

```
INDEX(x, y)  -- In this order
```

That will be effective with

```
WHERE x >= $x-$radius 
  AND x <= $x+$radius
```

but not for filtering on `y`.

And it will (probably) avoid the "filesort" for `ORDER BY x ASC, y ASC`.  Note that the index order must match this order.

Provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for any attempted `SELECT`.

And, please switch to InnoDB before MyISAM is removed.

[*Here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) is a quick cookbook on indexing in MySQL.

Comment: I created index `gmp (x, y, id, terrain, occupied, c_type)`, and running EXPLAIN on my above query shows id
select_type
table
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
Extra
1
SIMPLE
map
range
gmp
gmp
8
NULL
1955
Using where; Using index